# retrieving the module object on Lua

Tags: lua, lua-api

I have a C program that uses Lua to run some scripts. I need to open the Lua libraries via C code like `luaopen_socket_core(myLuaState)`, for some reasons I can't load the modules from the Lua code, like `socket = require "luasocket"`.

Once understood the idea of this program now I need to load a library called [struct](http://www.inf.puc-rio.br/~roberto/struct/), so I added the `struct.c` to my project, and when I tried to use its functions like `struct.unpack` the runtimer complains that there is no global variable called `struct`. Of course it was loaded with `luaopen_struct(myLuaState)` instead of `struct = require "struct"` which is forbidden for me.

Any suggestion about an way of having this `struct` variable available?

Comment: Try `struct = package.loaded.struct`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at [`luaL_requiref`](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#luaL_requiref) in the auxiliary library, which mimics `require` called from Lua.

You probably called the open-function directly and forgot to set those variables manually, that function would do it all for you.

Comment: Why this may be helpful?  Open-function `luaopen_struct` invokes `luaL_register`, so global `struct` and `package.loaded` are set correctly already.

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff: Seems you have a badly-behaved module-init function then. A module should not register itself, but let the caller register it however he wants: Just return the module-table.

Comment: Yes, that's the answer, now it worked perfectly fine. Thanks.

Comment: @Deduplicator - Please download the source and look at `struct.c`:393 (function `LUALIB_API int luaopen_struct`).  Does this function "badly-behaved"?

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff: No. Please take a hard look at line 40-44 and 393-396: For Lua 5.2 (2011) and newer it only returns the table, as it should. (Took link from the question) They needed some time to figure out how to properly do modules, especially as they changed the support-structure and that simplified things.

Comment: @Deduplicator - Oops!  Unexpected feature.  Thanks.